# Using ChangeDisplaySettingsEx in Delphi to set primary monitor

Tags: windows, delphi

I'm trying to use  ChangeDisplaySettingsEx in Delphi 7 to set a specific monitor as Primary.
In Windows.pas, it is defined as

```
function ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(lpszDeviceName: PChar; var lpDevMode: TDeviceMode;
        wnd: HWND; dwFlags: DWORD; lParam: Pointer): Longint; stdcall;
```

In [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183413(VS.85).aspx), the documentation for ChangeDisplaySettingsEx has the following comment for lpDevMode: "If lpDevMode is NULL, all the values currently in the registry will be used for the display setting."

My objective is to change the Primary monitor on a system with two active monitors, without changing anything else - resolution, bit depth, etc, should all remain the same. It seems like passing lpDevMode as null (nil) is the method that is provided to accomplish this.

However, lpDevMode is defined as a packed record type (TDeviceMode), not a pointer type, in Delphi's Windows.pas. Apparently, the Delphi interface to the Windows API performs the translation to the pointers used by Windows API 'behind the scenes'.

I tried calling it like this:

```
var
   alldevs : array[0..maxdev] of TDisplayDevice;
   lpDevMode : pointer;

begin
   lpDevMode := nil;
   lparam := nil;
   my_hwnd := nil;

  {... snip....}

  with alldevs[NewPri] do
      ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(devicename,TDeviceMode(lpDevMode),my_hwnd,CDS_SET_PRIMARY,lparam);
```

That gives me an invalid typecast error on "TDeviceMode(lpDevMode)". How can I pass a null pointer to ChangeDisplaySettingsEx?  Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

This is my findings after browsing numerous C++ and Delphi posts around the internet.

- did not want to declare a new TMyDevMode type with union options for missing fields
- use existing TDevMode type but set missing fields with Move() memcopy command and 32bit signed temporary variable
- move away current primary desktop from 0,0 pos, do not apply changes yet
- set new current primary desktop to 0,0 with CDS_SET_PRIMARY flag, do not apply changes yet
- xy position and width,height should not overlap but it seems Win7 can resolve some problems by itself
- call ChangeDisplaySettingsEx with null parameters to apply all pending changes

Set dmPosition.x and dmPosition.y values, use memory offset:

```
var dm: TDevMode;
var tempx, tempy: Integer;
Move(tempx, dm.dmOrientation, sizeOf(tempx));
Move(tempy, dm.dmPaperLength, sizeOf(tempy));
```

Get dmPosition.x and dmPosition.y values, use memory offset:

```
var dm: TDevMode;
var tempx, tempy: Integer;
Move(dm.dmOrientation, tempx, sizeOf(tempx));
Move(dm.dmPaperLength, tempy, sizeOf(tempy));
```

Set primary desktop from display1 to display2 instance. Make changes then apply all pending changes:

```
flags := CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY or CDS_NORESET;
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx('\\.\DISPLAY1', devMode1, 0, flags, nil);
flags := CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY or CDS_SET_PRIMARY or CDS_NORESET;
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx('\\.\DISPLAY2', devMode2, 0, flags, nil);
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(nil, PDeviceMode(0)^, 0, 0, nil);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(devicename, PDeviceMode(0)^, my_hwnd, CDS_SET_PRIMARY,
  lparam);
```

it does at least compile on Delphi 2009. I can't test it though.

**Edit:**

According to the scarce information on the net ([this is the most detailed I could find](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.wxwidgets.devel/107106)) changing the primary display isn't a simple process, so you may be missing a step along the way. I have two monitors, but can't change the primary device at all, not even with the control panel - looks like the dual-head display card driver doesn't allow it. The following therefore isn't tested, but maybe it will help you:

In order to set a new primary display you have to move the current primary display away from the (0, 0) position first. This is more tricky than it needs to be, because the Delphi `Windows.pas` file has an incomplete TDeviceMode type. It is given as

```
_devicemodeA = record
  dmDeviceName: array[0..CCHDEVICENAME - 1] of AnsiChar;
  ...
  dmOrientation: SHORT;
  dmPaperSize: SHORT;
  dmPaperLength: SHORT;
  dmPaperWidth: SHORT;
  dmScale: SHORT;
  dmCopies: SHORT;
  dmDefaultSource: SHORT;
  dmPrintQuality: SHORT;
  dmColor: SHORT;
  ...
end;
```

when it should instead be

```
_devicemodeA = record
  dmDeviceName: array[0..CCHDEVICENAME - 1] of AnsiChar;
  ...
  case boolean of
    FALSE: (
      dmOrientation: SHORT;
      dmPaperSize: SHORT;
      dmPaperLength: SHORT;
      dmPaperWidth: SHORT;
      dmScale: SHORT;
      dmCopies: SHORT;
      dmDefaultSource: SHORT;
      dmPrintQuality: SHORT;
    );
    TRUE: (
      dmPosition: TPoint;
      dmDisplayOrientation: DWORD;
      dmDisplayFixedOutput: DWORD;
    );
    dmColor: SHORT;
  ...
end;
```

You should add the fixed record type to your sources, as you need `dmPosition` to adjust the origin of the displays. It should go something like this:

```
// get current display settings
EnumDisplaySettings(PChar(AOldPrimaryDevice), ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS, DevMode1);
EnumDisplaySettings(PChar(ANewPrimaryDevice), ENUM_REGISTRY_SETTINGS, DevMode2);

// move old primary display to new position
DevMode1.dmFields := DM_POSITION;
DevMode1.dmPosition.x := DevMode2.dmPelsWidth;
DevMode1.dmPosition.y := 0;
Win32Check(ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(PChar(AOldPrimaryDevice), DevMode1, 0,
  CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY or CDS_NORESET, nil)):

// move old secondary display to (0, 0) and make the primary display
DevMode2.dmFields := DM_POSITION;
DevMode2.dmPosition.x := 0;
DevMode2.dmPosition.y := 0;
Win32Check(ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(PChar(ANewPrimaryDevice), DevMode2, 0,
  CDS_SET_PRIMARY or CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY or CDS_NORESET or DM_DISPLAYFLAGS, nil)):

// magic ???
Win32Check(ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(nil, PDeviceMode(0)^, 0, 0, nil));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That does compile, but it doesn't actually work. ChangeDisplaySettingsEx returns 0 (success), but the primary monitor remains unchanged.

Comment: mghie - thanks for the detailed information. I didn't know about having to adjust the display origins before setting the primary. 
I can't get back to solving this issue right now, but when I do, I'll let you know and post any working code here.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't verified it, but there's a post in the [MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowssdk/thread/95267766-8416-4f8a-be76-881ca8f32cc3/) that covers this and includes C++ code.  The "primary" monitor is the one at position 0,0, so you need to rearrange the positions of the monitors to make that happen.